# inet_addr functionality in erlang

Tags: erlang, erlang-ports

As the question says, is there any function or module that performs the functionality of `inet_addr` ?

Results from google isnt suggesting any direct way or am i missing something ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use inet_parse:address, and then convert the resuting list to binary. e.g.

```
16> list_to_binary(tuple_to_list(element(2,inet_parse:address("192.168.42.2")))).
```

<<192,168,42,2>>

Comment: No, this does not work for some thing like "arunmu.id". where as passing the same to inet_addr would give me a binary in network byte format. Any other suggestions ?

Comment: Are you saying your inet_addr() function does a DNS lookup if you pass it "arunmu.id" ? That's certainly non-standard behavior, more similar to gethostbyname(),  as the standard inet_addr() function expects an IP address in dotted quad format. You can probably use inet:gethostbyname() in erlang though